# How to use the same variable in different functions in GUI MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, get, set, matlab-guide

I have a popup menu with the following code. There are two options as C1 and C2. If the user selects C1, I want to set the value as 10 and if the user selcts C2, I want to set the value as 20.

```
function pop_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

contents = cellstr(get(hobject,'String'));
A = contents{get(hObject,'Value')};
if (strcmp(A,'C1'))
    X = 10;
elseif (strcmp(A,'C2'))
    X = 20;
end
set(handles.pop,X)
```

I want to use another function with a pushbutton and static text to display the answer, where the output is, Whatever the set value + 12.

```
function push_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

inX = get(handles.pop,X);
out = inX + 12;
set(handles.ans,'String',out)
```

However, I have some error in set and get function and thus I am in trouble. Help please.

Comment: I would just recommend to use [`setappdata`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html) and [`getappdata`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getappdata.html). And have a read at [Share Data Among Callbacks](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html).

Comment: Thank You, Helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid using globals you can use the UserData property of the figure window (assuming the uiobjects are children of the same figure). For example:

```
function pop_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

% ...

set( ancestor(hObject,'figure'), 'UserData', X )
```

and

```
function push_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

inX = get( ancestor(hObject,'figure'), 'UserData' );
out = inX + 12;
set(handles.ans,'String',out)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try the global variables

```
function pop_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
global X;
contents = cellstr(get(hobject,'String'));
A = contents{get(hObject,'Value')};
if (strcmp(A,'C1'))
X = 10;
elseif (strcmp(A,'C2'))  
X = 20;
set(handles.pop,X)
end
```

and use the same line of code global X; inside any function wherever you want to use the variable x.

```
function push_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
global X;
out = X + 12;
set(handles.ans,'String',out)
```

Any change of value to that X, in any function, is visible to all the functions that declare it as global.

Comment: I read about using a global function, but yet I had issues creating a global function. I kept getting an error saying 'hObject' is not defined. I used **User Data** and it is working now, Thank you. Very Helpful.